# Can't restore from TM backup in recovery mode

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, time-machine, recovery

I think I did very bad thing .. After restarting the mac and entering recovery mode and selecting Disk Utility I did erase "Apple SSD SM0256F Media" hard drive with all its partitions including Macintosh HD then I did erase Macintosh HD again with giving it a name instead of "untitled", now I don't have any operating system, after that I select restore from TM backup and I select last backup and it start erasing Macintosh HD then I get an error

> an error occurred while adding a recovery system to the destination
>   disk

I did verify the disk and repair it , i got no problem all disk partitions are ok .

My computer: MacBook Pro mid 2014

And this is a list of all partitions from terminal :

[image]

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solve it :

- Enter recovery mode
- Select Reinstall new macOS, it start downloading an old one
  (Mavericks).
- it will start installing the OS.
- after it finished it will restart and it will come the setup steps.
- Now the mac is working , restart and enter the recovery mode again
- but this time to restore backup from TM which is what I want.

  **Now it will restore without any errors .**

What I did notice is after executing the `diskutil list` command again , I saw a new partition on the root hard drive which is `Apple_Boot Recovery HD` I think this is the problem it was missing, also it explain why when I press Command+R it takes me to internet recovery mode not the normal one.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

On a 2012 MacBookPro the network boot image is Mavericks and that results in the messages reported by the OP when attempting a restore. Rather than performing a full install as suggested above, all that's needed is to create a High Sierra bootable USB as per https://support.apple.com/en-gb/ht201372, boot from the USB, and immediately select "Restore from a Time Machine Backup". The restore from a High Sierra boot works, whereas the Mavericks one does not.

Comment: This procedure also works for Catalina on a 2012 MacBook Air, though the first time around the restore was stuck at the "Finishing" step for hours. Forced power down, rebooted from USB, selected Restore and second time it completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Please restart from Internet Recovery. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.

If you see a globe at startup than your are in internet Recovery. This will need some time because the specific system for your Mac will download from Apple.

Open Disk Utility choose the system drive on the left side (the drive named as "Macintosh HD" not the root drive), and click erase. Give the drive a name such as "Macintosh HD" for example.

If this operation done without errors, close disk utility and try to restore your drive from Time Machine.

Comment: Thank you but you are repeating what I already did exactly and still having the error when I try to restore from TM

Comment: The Recovery Mode is different from Internet Recovery,  I didn't read anything above that you have reboot into Internet Recovery - Sorry if you have do it and the problem exists please leave a comment here.

Comment: Actually I cant enter the recovery mode , when I press and hold Command+R without pressing option key , it show the global and start downloading and it takes me to internet recovery , anyway I did exactly what you're saying and I got no errors during erasing also I did repair and verify the disk and the desk is ok , but still getting the error when I try to restore from TM backup

Comment: Are you able to make a clean install - if so, do it first, upgrade your system at the current system that you've before and try to restore TM.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fidget with the Core Storage volumes and get past the recovery disk error.

Not sure if it's actually doing anything though. About two hours of silence and an uninformative progress bar where I would have expected to hear the backup disk going clackety clack.

## Recovering Mac Mini from Time Machine Backup

I have a Mac Mini 2012 with a ~120GB + 1TB fusion drive.

I borked it up a little while trying to install an Ubuntu dual boot and was unable to restore it from my Time Machine backup due to "There was an error creating recovery disk".

To fix that I removed all volumes of all types from the disk and started over, leaving 5gb of space for the recovery partition to be created.

Since I now know what the table ended up looking like (which I'll post back... tomorrow after the backup is restored), I'm confident that I could have done this by resizing as well.

## DANGER

All of these commands are very dangerous if you have data on your disk(s).

I'm using the actual commands that I would use, which are the actual commands that someone else with a factory-installed fusion drive would need to use.

Unless the reason that you're trying to add a recovery drive happens to be that your drive is already utterly messed up, I would NOT recommend following these steps.

HOWEVER, they may come in as a handy references in addition to other instructions in these posts.

## Inspecting Volumes

Look to see what's there and make proper judgements first:

```bsh
# See all physical partitions
diskutil list

# See all core storage volumes
diskutil cs list
```

## Removing all volumes

Then delete whatever needs to be deleted:

```bsh
# Delete a Logical Volume
diskutil cs deleteVolume <lvUUID>

# Delete a Physical Volume
diskutil cs deleteDisk <pvUUID>

# Delete a Logical Volume Group (everything)
diskutil cs delete <lvgUUID>
```

Recreate the partition table from scratch, if needed:

```bsh
# Re-partition and format the HDD
# `R` means Remainder
# `5G` means ~4.7GiB
diskutil partitionDisk disk0 2 GPT \
    JHFS+ Macintosh\ HD R \
    JHFS+ Recovery\ HD 5G

# Re-partition and format the SSD
# the remainder, `R`, is 100% of the usable disk space
diskutil partitionDisk disk1 1 GPT \
    JHFS+ Macintosh\ HD R
```

## Create Core Storage

This will be "Macintosh HD" as you know and love

```bsh
# Create a logical volume group named "Macintosh HD"
diskutil cs create Macintosh\ HD disk0s2 disk1

# Create a volume (of the same name) using 100% of the group
diskutil cs createVolume <lvgUUID> jhfs+ Macintosh\ HD 100%
```

Note: you may want to reboot at this stage to ensure that the volumes are in the right order.

## Unmount all-the-things

```bsh
diskutil unmount "Macintosh HD"
diskutil unmount "Recovery HD"
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1
```

## Free up space

The purpose of creating "Recovery HD" previously - assuming the scenario where you want to restore from a Time Machine backup - is just to reserve extra space at the end of one of the disks so that it doesn't get absorbed into any other volume.

Now it's time to free it back up so that the restore process can create it again.

First check again to see what partitions exist. The numbers *should* match the output of `diskutil`, but if not either reboot or trust `gpt` over `diskutil`.

The `size`s are not listed in bytes but sectors, which are probably 4KiB. It may be better to tell which is which by ratio than by exact size.

```bsh
gpt -r show /dev/disk0
```

Now remove the partition corresponding to "Recovery HD". After a reboot that had changed from `disk0s3` to `disk0s4` for me.

```bsh
gpt remove -i 4
```

After that I stopped getting the error about not being able to create a recovery partition. I'll find out tomorrow if the TM recovery actually worked. I'm not sure it will as I don't hear much in the way of disk activity on the backup drive. :-/

## Resources

- https://blog.fosketts.net/2011/08/05/undocumented-corestorage-commands/
- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2014030311173257

## Note: resizing core storage

Many of the things I looked at only showed how to resize AND create a new volume, but you can resize without creating a new volume.

```
# First resize the logical volume
diskutil coreStorage resizeVolume <lvUUID> 1T

# Next resize the physical volume
diskutil coreStorage resizeDisk <pvUUID> 997G

# Tada! You have free space!
```

## Note: Set Recovery HD`s type

I was not able to get success by creating a blank recovery volume. However, if you have the BaseSystem.dmg and are able to restore it, you may want to set the volume type to be a hidden recovery partition.

```bsh
# Unmount to be able to make changes
diskutil unmount /dev/disk0s3

# Change the type from Apple_HFS to Apple_Boot
asr adjust -target /dev/disk0s3 -settype Apple_Boot
```